# Why when adding dll file from Class Library project i'm getting error: Error on error Provider1?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I used this website for the example of creating Custom Control in thiscase textBox:

[Custom Control](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ehtesham.dotnet/how-to-create-a-custom-control/)

In the Class Library project i built the project and i have the dll file.
Then in my Windows Forms project on the took box i did choose items when i select the dll file i see it was added to the dll files list but i don't see this purple sign near it:

This is a screenshot of the windows forms project when added the dll file.

[image: Error Custom TextBox]

On the left the dll after loaded it called: ExtdTextBox but on it's left near it there is no this purple sign.

Then in the form1 designer you see the textBox after dragging it.

And on the right on the solution explorer on the bottom you see the error i'm getting:

Error on errorProviler1

This is the class i added to my Class Library project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;

namespace CustomControl
{
    public class ExtdTextBox : TextBox
    {
        #region Member Variables
        Color waterMarkColor = Color.Gray;
        Color forecolor;
        Font font;
        Font waterMarkFont;
        string waterMarkText = "Your Text Here";
        #endregion 
        #region Constructor
        public ExtdTextBox()
        {
            base.Text = this.waterMarkText;
            this.forecolor = this.ForeColor;
            this.ForeColor = this.waterMarkColor;
           this.font = this.Font;
            //event handlers
            this.TextChanged += new EventHandler(ExtdTextBox_TextChanged);
            this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(ExtdTextBox_KeyPress);
            this.LostFocus += new EventHandler(ExtdTextBox_TextChanged);
        }
        #endregion
        #region Event Handler Methods
        void ExtdTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text))
            {
                this.ForeColor = this.forecolor;
                this.Font = this.font;
            }
            else
            {
                this.TextChanged -= new EventHandler(ExtdTextBox_TextChanged);
                base.Text = this.waterMarkText;
                this.TextChanged += new EventHandler(ExtdTextBox_TextChanged);
                this.ForeColor = this.waterMarkColor;
                this.Font = this.waterMarkFont;
            }
        }
       void ExtdTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            string str = base.Text.Replace(this.waterMarkText, "");
            this.TextChanged -= new EventHandler(ExtdTextBox_TextChanged);
            this.Text = str;
            this.TextChanged += new EventHandler(ExtdTextBox_TextChanged);
        }
        #endregion
        #region User Defined Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// Property to set/get Watermark color at design/runtime
        /// </summary>
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("Extended Properties")]
       [Description("sets Watermark color")]
        [DisplayName("WaterMark Color")]
        public Color WaterMarkColor
        {
            get
            {
                return this.waterMarkColor;
            }
            set
            {
                this.waterMarkColor = value;
                base.OnTextChanged(new EventArgs());
            }
        }
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("Extended Properties")]
        [Description("sets TextBox text")]
        [DisplayName("Text")]
        /// <summary>
        /// Property to get Text at runtime(hides base Text property)
        /// </summary>
        public new string Text
        {
            get
            {
                //required for validation for Text property
                return base.Text.Replace(this.waterMarkText, string.Empty);
            }
            set
            {
                base.Text = value;
            }
        }
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("Extended Properties")]
        [Description("sets WaterMark font")]
        [DisplayName("WaterMark Font")]
        /// <summary>
        /// Property to get Text at runtime(hides base Text property)  
      /// </summary>
        public Font WaterMarkFont
        {
            get
            {
                //required for validation for Text property
                return this.waterMarkFont;
            }
            set
            {
                this.waterMarkFont = value;
                this.OnTextChanged(new EventArgs());
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        ///  Property to set/get Watermark text at design/runtime
        /// </summary>
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("Extended Properties")]
        [Description("sets Watermark Text")]
        [DisplayName("WaterMark Text")]
        public string WaterMarkText
        {
            get
            {
                return this.waterMarkText;
            }
            set
            {
                this.waterMarkText = value;
                base.OnTextChanged(new EventArgs());
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The class library project is like in the website example i created new project under c# > windows > windows forms control library

.net 4.5 since my windows forms project i want to add the dll to is also .net 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error; it's a property named `Error` provided by the [`ErrorProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx) component. This component lets you associate an error message to any control.